# How to create a form with checkboxes and a hoverable dropdown menu to chose action

Tags: html, web

I would like to implement the following. A table with a checkbox in a cell for every row. To submit the form a dropdown menu offers the different actions to take (move, delete, etc).

It would look like:

[image]

The submit button would be a hoverable dropdown with different actions:

[image]

The working code for the table:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">        
    <table>
      @foreach ($tags as $tag)
      <tr>
        <td>
           <br>{{$tag->title}}</br>
        </td>                
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name={{$tag->title}} value="true"><br> 
        </td> 
      </tr>     
      @endforeach
    </table>
  </form>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Potential code for the hoverable menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

How could this be achieved? A form has only one action for the button and how to make the submit button into a hoverable dropdown?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="mypage.php">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="submit" value="dropdown" />
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <table border="1" style="width: 160px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>rugby</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="rugby" name="sport[]"/></td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>tennis</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="tennis" name="sport[]" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You select elements from the dropdown menu and then you click on the button sumbit to send them to a PHP page as an array. The css I've used is the same shown in the link of the dropdown menu.
This is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean with this. I tried it on google chrome and if I put the arrow over the button, the menu drops down